# Constraints in a Container View

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I am trying to build an on-boarding sequence with a pageviewcontroller and right now I have three viewcontrollers nested as such:

1. PageContainerViewController holds : The PageViewController and Page Control Dots
2. PageViewController holds: ContentViewController (and all the data)
3. ContentViewController holds: ImageView (full screen) and a label with some text.

So everything works out okay, but since my text must be at the bottom of the screen near the page control dots, I was wondering how to set the constraints of the label (which is an element of 3) so that it would constrain to the top of the page control dots (which is an element of 1). I don't want there to be a chance they'll overlap on any size screen. The dots have to stay static, the text should be all swipe-y with the image.

Another way to frame my question would be: Can you constrain an item in a child view of a containerviewcontroller to the position of an item in its parent view?

Is this possible? I feel like this is already a tangled mess, but I was unable to find a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Edit: [Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyzqB.png)

Comment: Can you post screenshots and which one is child and which one is parent??

Comment: Edited to add a screenshot.

Comment: So you want to constrain label to bottom where the text wow is??

Comment: Yes. Right now label can be multiple lines and I don't want that to end up overlapping anything.

Comment: Have you used auto layout constraints??

Comment: I tried constraining to "nearest neighbor" but that constrains it to the bottom of the ContentViewController and not "Wow!"

Comment: You can only constraint to views which are in the same controller view not in different controller view :)